# Legacy code seems to have an overflow, I'm not sure though

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm working at some legacy code right now (converting some of it to C#), and I've stumbled upon a problem:

A byte array is created (length is ulcLen):

```
CSLAutoArray<BYTE> pMem(new BYTE[ulcLen]);
```

Now some stuff is put into the byte array, after which a CRC / Hash value is supposed to be written to the first four bytes (ULONG / UInt32):

```
__CfgCRC(pMem + sizeof(ULONG), ulcLen - sizeof(ULONG))
```

->

```
inline ULONG __CfgCRC(const void* const cpcMem, const ULONG ulcMemSize)
{
  ULONG ulRes = 0;

  const BYTE* const cpcUseMem = reinterpret_cast<const BYTE*>(cpcMem);
  for(const BYTE* pcLook = cpcUseMem; cpcUseMem + ulcMemSize > pcLook; pcLook++)
  {
    ulRes ^= static_cast<ULONG>(*pcLook);
    //[...]
  };

  return ulRes;
};
```

Now, is it just me, or is the static_cast reading 1/2/3 bytes over the end of the byte array, at the end of the for loop? Since pcLook (the memory pointer) is increased until it reaches the full length of the data, (ulclen + sizeof(ULONG)) ? Or am I wrong? Or does static_cast somehow not read over the end of an array ? (CSLAutoArray is some kind of managed pointer class, but as far as I see it does not interfere with this code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*pcLook` is just a `BYTE` so no, it's only reading 1 octet at a time.  the cast just casts the `BYTE` and not what `pcLock` is pointing to.

Comment: OKAY!!! So how does it cast 1 byte to 4 ? Does the mean the resulting ULONG can also only have a max value of 255 ?

Comment: typically `BYTE` is `unsigned char` so it would zero-extend it to the size of the `ULONG`... and yes, it would still have a value range of {0...255}.